# Calculating a path integral using Kelvin-Stokes theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

I have the following question: 
"Let $ C = \{ (x,y,z) | x+2y+3z = 4, x^2 +y^2 =2x \} $ which is a one-dimensional smooth manifold. 
Let $ \varphi: [0,4] \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ be a simple loop that its image is C, and we know that: 
$ \varphi(0) = (0,0,\frac 43), \varphi(2) = (2,0,\frac 23) , \varphi(3) = (1,1,\frac 13)$ 
Calculate the integarl: 
$\oint_\varphi Pdx + Qdy + Rdz $ 
where:
$ P = x+2y + 3z, Q= y + 2z + 3x, R= z + 2x + 3y$" 
From what I understand, there is some kind of application of the Kelvin-Stokes theorem, but I have no idea how to implement this theorem here. I could use some help with this.

Comment: "No idea how to implement this theorem here" doesn't give us a lot to go on if we can't read your mind. Do feel comfortable with Kelvin-Stokes in simpler contexts? Which parts of it you've been able to identify here? What is different about this context that's making it harder/what brick wall are you hitting?

Comment: Unfortunately, in our course, they didn't really teach us how to use the KS theorem in "simpler contexts", they gave us one example which is kind of complex, so I'm not very familiar with how to use it.
I can see the path integral which is in the KS theorem, however, the theorem that I have learned requires a mapping from $ \mathbb R^2 $ to $ \mathbb R^3 $ which makes several assumptions.
I'm trying to understand the main idea behind using the KS theorem, or maybe a different way, to calculate the integral.

Comment: That context is extremely helpful. I recommend reading through standard/lower level multivariable calculus discussions of Kelvin-Stokes from another source like [Paul's Math Notes](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcIII/stokestheorem.aspx) or [Openstax](https://openstax.org/books/calculus-volume-3/pages/6-7-stokes-theorem) and then come back to this.